# How to stretch the content in html

Tags: html, css

I have this content, however, I want to stretch the content to make it fit as a whole. Need help!

```css
.subtext10 {
  margin-left: 210px;
  margin-top: 90px;
  font-size: 9.2pt;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text5">
  <p class="subtext10">has equipped me with the knowledge in modules such as
    <br>Business Environment, Service Excellence,
    <br>Entrepreneurship, Executive Lounge Service,
    <br>Housekeeping Services, Hospitality Sales & Marketing
    <br>and Event & Catering Management which are
    <br>essential in the field</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the break tags (`<br>`) and the margins:

Block-level elements, such as paragraphs (`<p>`) and divs, will naturally stretch the full available width of their containers. Read more about a [***block formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting).

```css
.subtext10 {
  font-size: 9.2pt;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text5">
  <p class="subtext10">has equipped me with the knowledge in modules such as Business
     Environment, Service Excellence, Entrepreneurship, Executive Lounge Service,
     Housekeeping Services, Hospitality Sales & Marketing and Event & Catering Management
     which are essential in the field</p>
</div>
```